# Little vertical misaligment between columns

Tags: margins, line-spacing

I've a little misalignment problem in my document. 
[image: problematic part]

In the preamble, there is (among other things):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twocolumn, twoside]{book}  
\usepackage{lettrine}
\def\LettrineWord#1#2 {\lettrine{#1}{#2} }

\newcommand*{\isok}[2][]{
\def\tmp##1##2 {\lettrine[#1]{##1}{##2} }
\tmp#2
}
```

And in the document's body:

```
\textbf{3. joulukuuta 1984, Bhopal, Intia}
\isok{Foobar barfoo} \blindtext
```

My question is: what is best way handle vertical misalignment between columns? I guess that blank line between "3. joulukuuta" and "Foobar" is narrower than other lines.

EDIT:
I found an acceptable method:

```
\textbf{3. joulukuuta 1984, Bhopal}\vspace{-\parskip}\vspace{\baselineskip}
```

However, there may be still better way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try adding a `\vspace{some length}`,  just after the boldface text,  the length value having to be found by trial and error – something like `\vspace{0.5ex}`.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  the problem here is possibly that the space available for the text is not an integral number of lines, and `flushbottom` is in effect.  you might try using `\raggedbottom` for this page, but this may not have the result you want either.  another thing to try is using `\enlargethispage` (on both columns) to make the right-hand column just long enough to accommodate another line of text (or the left-hand column shorter by the amount of vertical distance between the left and right-hand columns).

Comment: not really possible to tell what is happening from the fragments but apart from the vertical mis-alignment it looks like your lettrine is adding a double space after the second word, is that intended?